# Scoring of the Wechsler Nonverbal Scale of Ability

Tags: test, iq

How is the global test score supposed to be computed based on the individual scores in the Wechsler Nonverbal Scale of Ability?

Let's say the sub-test scores are A, B, C, and D.

From there:

- how do we obtain the global score? is it age dependent?
- I understand that the standard deviation on the total score is 15. Is this correct?
- how is the confidence interval computed? is it symmetric around the "measured" value?

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Tulio_Otero/publication/298348271_The_Wechsler_Nonverbal_Test_of_Ability_WVN_Assessment_of_Diverse_Learners/links/56e8383b08ae166360e4fac3/The-Wechsler-Nonverbal-Test-of-Ability-WVN-Assessment-of-Diverse-Learners.pdf may help with your question